# Rotate object under gravity force

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a scenario where there's a radial gravity field. In this scene, there's also an object built by two physics bodies with a different mass.

When I run this code, the radial gravity field is created correctly and the body goes to gravityCenter.
I'm expecting that the body rotates too because the head is heavier than the tail but this doesn't happend.

Why?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myobj")

    let myCategory : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

        let gravityCenter = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField()
        gravityCenter.isEnabled = true
        gravityCenter.position = CGPoint(x: size.width, y: size.height * 0.5)
        gravityCenter.strength = 0.5
        addChild(gravityCenter)

        object.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.1, y: size.height * 0.9)
        object.scale(to: CGSize(width: 100, height: 25))

        let head = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: object.size.width/5, center: CGPoint(x: object.size.width/2, y: 0))
        let tail = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: object.size.width/50, center: CGPoint(x: -object.size.width/2, y: 0))

        head.mass = 500
        head.categoryBitMask = myCategory
        head.allowsRotation = true
        head.isDynamic = true
        head.angularDamping = 0
        head.affectedByGravity = true

        tail.mass = 2
        tail.categoryBitMask = myCategory
        tail.allowsRotation = true
        tail.isDynamic = true
        tail.angularDamping = 0
        tail.affectedByGravity = true

        object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: [head, tail])
        object.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = myCategory
        object.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        object.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
        object.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
        object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

        addChild(object)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, from a physics standpoint SpriteKit is behaving correctly.  If you think about it, more mass *does* mean more gravitational force, but it also means more inertia, which exactly cancels out the increased force.  Perhaps introduce a little bit of `linearDamping` into the tail?  That would get the body to rotate by making the head drag the tail a little bit.

Comment: yes, but can I set the friction in the gravity field? With friction, the heavier physics body should reach the center before the other one.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can do that with `SKPhysicsField`. Say, here's an idea: why don't you set up another radial gravity field and set its strength to a small negative value so that it repels, then make it apply to just the tail?  That would get the tail to rotate away from the center.